# Send Logging Marketing Cloud Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, dataextensions, logging

we wanted to create a Send Log DE.

We went to create a DataExtension based on the SendLog template.

But as shown in screenshot we do NOT have the option to see and choose the sendLog template for our Data Extension.

[image: No Send Log Template available]

Do you know if anything must be enabled before we can use the SendLog template?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, so others can see this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The Send Logging feature needs to be enabled in your account for this template to be available. So you need to reach out to your account executive or log a new case in salesforce help & training portal where you ask for "Send Logging feature activation".

> Your account must use the send logging and data extension features. Contact your relationship manager for more information about enabling these features.
>   (Source: [Marketing Cloud documentation on Send Logging](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/))

**Further reading:**

- [Unleash the power of Send Logging](https://markus.codes/2017/07/20/unleash-the-power-of-send-logging-in-marketing-cloud) (info on needed features and further info on how to utilize the entire feature set of send logging)

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for you to see the send log template, even if it is enabled, they just give you a few column names. you can directly go to the salesforce marketing cloud documentation and search for send log table and create a DE on your own by seeing the attributes